# Get params inside a Ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It there a way to read the params inside a class of a gem
I tried require "cgi" and require "action_pack" but no chance...
Any clues ?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Be more precise.  The params of what?  A submitted form?

If yes, you could do that:

```
require "cgi"

...

cgi = CGI.new
h = cgi.params

login = h['login'][0]
password = h['password'][0]
```

and so on.

Comment: Yeah exactly i want to patch a gem containing some logic according to the parameters I get from the user 's request. I try what you proposed and mark the answer later on if it successful

Answer (score 0):

It seems that CGI.new creates a new object and does not contain the params of current request

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/) middleware for this. See also http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware for a tutorial.